# Unknown error occurred while loading Library/Artifacts unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

> Unknown error occurred while loading 'Library/Artifacts/91/919a792b1979b62f241964f8b62a0554'.

This error I get after download entities on unity

Comment: Well , what you need?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions: download the latest version of the package; Try deleting the entire "Library" folder, after having dubbed it to another location for safety.